# How to keep an image and its padding and margin from overflowing a sidebar?

Tags: css

I am unable to do add these without the image and its border flowing beyond the sidebar. You can see what I mean by visiting the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8p9m27an/5/

Please note, I am not allowed to change the HTML.

My biggest confusion is how to get the border, padding, margin, etc to fit in the sidebar. I used `width: 100%`, but I suppose that is just for the image itself. What is the alternative so that all of the mentioned will take up 100% of the sidebar, not just the image itself?

I understand I could set `width` to 9x%, however that does not seem like the appropriate solution. I feel there would be a way for CSS to "understand" I am trying to get everything to fit and to take up 100% width of the sidebar, all elements (padding px, border px, margin px, etc) included.

My current CSS:

CSS:

```
/*This is the class, .left, of the sidebar, 
which is an <aside> in the HTML. The img's are image links.*/

.left img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;*/
}

.left {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: scroll; /*I know I could simply cut off overflow, but
    instead I want to have everything contained */
  float: left;
}

/*body text*/ section {
  max-width: 85%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
}

a {
  background-color: rgb(0, 4, 255);
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<main>
  <aside class = "left">
    <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/>Image 1</a>
<a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/>Image 2</a>
<a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee">Image 3</a>
</aside>
<section class = "right">
<h2>Watch your Head </h2>
<p>Ultimate Frisbee is a sport that I never played myself, but it's popularity is something hard to ignore in many Midwestern college towns.  Students (and people who wish they were still students) spend the few briefs months of good weather, sprinting down fields, hurling frisbees, and yelling "Stack!!".</p>
                <p>What I find much more entertaining is the large number of people who continue to play when the weather gets windy and the night sky darkens around oh....4:15pm.  The sight of frisbees boomeranging in the wind is topped only by the knowledge that even when you can't seem, those same plastic discs of death are probably hurtling through the dark night sky at 8 or 9 o'clock in the evening.
                </p>
                <p>Ultimate Frisbee requires a great deal of stamina and dexterity.  Not surprisingly, the <abbr title = "International Olympic Committee">IOC</abbr> officially recognized Ultimate as a sport in 2015.   It can go up against other sports for inclusion in  Olympic games.</p>
            </section>
        </main>
```

Comment: you need to add `box-sizing:border-box` and then remove the margin from the width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following adjustments

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

to make the border/padding not to add to the width but to *eat* from the width.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Then

```
aside.left a {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

So that the links inside the `aside` do not overflow their container.

Lastly

```
.left img{
    /* width:100%;  remove this line from your rule*/ 
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

to make the images 100% of their container minus the left+right margins.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

---

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfhjs4ck/1/

Comment: Hi, thank you. I will continue to check out the links, they do look promising. I tried to make edits using your code, but I was unable to get the result. If possible you can help me see where I misunderstood - https://jsfiddle.net/teg012mj/1/ thank you.

Comment: @CodeWalrus added an updated fiddle in the answer (*at the bottom*)

Comment: Very cool, thanks! For future viewers, my misunderstanding was that I needed to add what Gabriele wrote to my CSS, not replace